# PLSQL Encountered the symbol "YES" when expecting one of the following

Tags: plsql

Hi I am trying to create aa table of summary stats using PLSQL. I am new to PLSQL. I keep getting this error. 
Encountered the symbol "YES" when expecting one of the following

Below is my code.

```
DECLARE
AGE NUMBER;
CAMPAIGN NUMBER;
PDAYS NUMBER;
PREVIOUS NUMBER;
POUTCOME NUMBER;
EMP_VAR_RATE NUMBER;
CONS_PRICE_IDX NUMBER;
CONS_CONF_IDX NUMBER;
EURIBOR3M NUMBER;
Y VARCHAR;


BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_STAT
AS

SELECT 
ROUND(AVG(AGE)) AS AVERAGE_AGE
,ROUND(AVG(CAMPAIGN)) AS AVERAGE_CONTACTS_MADE
,ROUND(AVG(PDAYS)) AS NO_DAYS_PASSED
,ROUND(AVG(PREVIOUS)) AS AVERAGE_PREVIOUS_CONTACTS_MADE
,ROUND(AVG(EMP_VAR_RATE)) AS AVERAGE_EMPLOYEE_VARIATION
,ROUND(AVG(CONS_PRICE_IDX)) AS AVERAGE_CONSUMER_PRICE_INDEX
,ROUND(AVG(CONS_CONF_IDX)) AS AVERAGE_CONSUMER_CONFIDENCE_INDEX
,ROUND(AVG(EURIBOR3M)) AS AVERAGE_EURIBOR
,COUNT(CASE WHEN Y = 'yes' THEN 1 end) AS NUMBER_CUSTOMERS_TOOK_DEPOSIT
,COUNT(CASE WHEN Y = 'no' THEN 1 end) AS NUMBER_CUSTOMERS_DIDNT_TAKE_DEPOSIT

FROM BANK_DATA
');

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have single quotes within a larger string. Unfortunately from the interpreter's view point your string in 'Create ... when Y = ' is one string and the next token is the word "yes" which the interpreter does not understand.  
You have 2 options:

1. double the quotes needed inside the larger string.
2. use the alternative [quote delimiter](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm).

Using quote delimiter you get:

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (q'[
CREATE TABLE SUMMARY_STAT
AS

SELECT 
ROUND(AVG(AGE)) AS AVERAGE_AGE
,ROUND(AVG(CAMPAIGN)) AS AVERAGE_CONTACTS_MADE
,ROUND(AVG(PDAYS)) AS NO_DAYS_PASSED
,ROUND(AVG(PREVIOUS)) AS AVERAGE_PREVIOUS_CONTACTS_MADE
,ROUND(AVG(EMP_VAR_RATE)) AS AVERAGE_EMPLOYEE_VARIATION
,ROUND(AVG(CONS_PRICE_IDX)) AS AVERAGE_CONSUMER_PRICE_INDEX
,ROUND(AVG(CONS_CONF_IDX)) AS AVERAGE_CONSUMER_CONFIDENCE_INDEX
,ROUND(AVG(EURIBOR3M)) AS AVERAGE_EURIBOR
,COUNT(CASE WHEN Y = 'yes' THEN 1 end) AS NUMBER_CUSTOMERS_TOOK_DEPOSIT
,COUNT(CASE WHEN Y = 'no' THEN 1 end) AS NUMBER_CUSTOMERS_DIDNT_TAKE_DEPOSIT
FROM BANK_DATA
]');

END;
```